# How to make caps lock only work with letters (on a German keyboard)

Tags: windows-10, default-settings, capslock, german

I feel like I've gone mad :) For 30 years as an IT admin and developer, when I've hit caps-lock it only shifted the letters (so that if I hit the number 1, I still got a number one).

Since migrating to Windows 10, when I hit caps-lock, it shifts the entire keyboard (so hitting "1" results in "!"). People are trying to tell my this is normal for Windows 10.

Is it possible to turn this off?

Comment: I think your keyboard layout file is custom or damaged. Restore it from OS installation disk.

Comment: Not confirmed. Just checked Windows 10 and Caps Lock does work in the same way as in Windows 7. It seems that @Akina is right.

Comment: I've worked with Windows 10 since release, both normal releases and Slow and Fast Ring for Preview releases and now support it on around 800 machines, and on none of these does CAPS LOCK behave how you describe. What you're seeing is not the "new normal" and something is broken on your system. You should start with the standard Windows 10 repair functions, DISM and SFC. Follow this guide, you should end up running DISM 3 times with different arguments, and then SFC a few times as well: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image

Comment: Could this have something to do with it being a German Keyboard (but an English install of Windows)? This is actually the second, independent Windows 10 machine on which this has happened.Both keyboards were by the manufacturer "Cherry" - although different computers, and different physical keyboards.

Comment: In *Settings > Time & Language > Language*, what is your your language: (1) English (Germany), (2) German (Germany) or (3) English US/UK with the addition of a German keyboard (and which)? (To address me in a new comment please add `@harrymc`.)

Comment: @harrymc. Thanks for the post. `Country or region`=Germany; `Windows Display Language`=English (United States); `Preferred Languages`= (In order) Deutsche (Deutschland), English (United States), English (en-DE). NOTE: Deutschland is first, otherwise the login screen keeps trying to use the English keyboard instead of the German one.; `Override for default input method`="Use language list" (because windows won't stay on "Germany (Germany) - German" when I set it there.

Comment: Real strange. Does this also happen when booting in Safe Mode?

Comment: @harrymc I haven't tried that, but I tried it with a bunch of different Windows 10 machines here (I'm a sys admin) and they all do it. I think it has to be related to the German keyboard. Its the only thing in common to all the machines.I updtaed the question to reflect this.

Comment: Does this happen in all keyboard layout modes? As an additional test, you might try to delete all other languages than "Deutsche (Deutschland)" to see if this is really how this keyboard works.

Comment: I have the same behavior as you using the Deutsch (Deutschland) keyboard. However, when switching to English (United States) using Alt-Shift the caps lock only applies to letters as you and any sane person would expect. So it definitely has something to do with the Windows keyboard layout for German...

Answer (score 1):

go to language settings - select German - select Options - add keyboard - look for QWERTZ (IBM) and then remove QWERTZ

Comment: Unfortunately, that stops it from being a German keyboard :) I still want it to be a German keyboard, just not do the silly caps lock stuff :D